# Why does my 9-patch loading screen look so funky?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, nine-patch

**Update**

I think I have a better understanding of the 9-patch file format now. It's getting better but I [still have some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163429/how-can-i-get-9-patch-to-center-my-image-on-a-cordova-launch-screen?noredirect=1#comment63755251_38163429).

**Original Post**

Now I know my art work isn't perfect and I'm probably not doing myself any favors with the comic sans, but there's something very wrong with the bottom left and bottom right heart lines in **Landscape >> Rendered on Nexus 5**, and the **Portrait >> Rendered on Nexus 5** has some extra flaws too.

I generated the 9-patches with https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

- XXXHDPI
- Zip download
- Content Padding (default settings)

They're being used in a Meteor Cordova Android app's launch screen.

## Landscape

**A 9-patch png file**
[image]

**Rendered on Nexus 5**
[image]

## Portrait

**A 9-patch png file**
[image]

**Rendered on Nexus 5**
[image]

Comment: What do you expect them to look like? It certainly looks like only the sections you've marked are getting smaller or larger.

Comment: I was hoping to just stretch the edges of the images out, and leave the center the same. I'm probably misunderstanding how 9-patch is meant to be used.

Comment: The left and top edges show the sections that *should* be stretched/compacted.

Comment: So it looks like maybe I made the 9-patch wrong for what I'm trying to do.  Presumably you mean the black / white lines (as rendered in my browser - chrome) shown on the left & top of the image indicate what should be stretched. Is it the black part which is supposed to remain the same and the white part which is supposed to be stretched?

Comment: The black parts on the left and top are what are stretched, the white parts are what are maintained exactly as they are

Comment: Presumably there's a way for me to inverse what I've demonstrated above? So the middle remains, and the outside stretches? I'm having trouble getting the online tool I found to do that, perhaps I'll try some desktop editors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stretch something diagonally using a nine-patch image.

To me it looks like you should forget using a nine-patch and just use a plain image and center it.

Comment: When I used a plain image the aspect ratio got out of whack.  Maybe there's a Cordova setting for centering the launch screen image?

Comment: @AnthonyAstige: You might have some luck with large margins and the `SplashMaintainAspectRatio` preference (look it up). Alternatively experiment with a custom `layer-list` drawable.

Comment: Ah yeah I see it now at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#android-quirks, hopefully it centers.  Maybe I'll give that a go, thanks!