# How can I get 9-patch to center my image on a cordova launch screen

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, nine-patch

I manually created a 9-patch .png as shown below / indicated here:

- Stretch areas

  - Top: Dot all the way to the left, dot all the way to the right
  - Left: Dot all the way at the top, dot all the way at the bottom
- Content area

  - Bottom: Line entire length of image
  - Right: Line the entire height of image

I expect it to render the image in the center both vertically and horizontally, however it's rendering too low vertically (and I'm not sure horizontally).

I may be misunderstanding the 9-patch rendering algorithm, like how it decides how much to stretch each area on a given axis. Or how Cordova tags the 9-patch for my Meteor application. Anything insights are welcome!

**My 9-patch**

[image]

**Rendering on Nexus 5**
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with cordova and meteor but I understand 9-patches pretty thoroughly, and your image seems fine for it to be stretched to be exactly in the center of the screen. Is there something (in cordova/meteor) that specifies the structure of your screen (like layout xml or something)?

Comment: [Meteor Mobile config](http://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html) links me to [Cordova config](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref/index.html#The%20config.xml%20File_core_configuration_elements). My understanding is I'm supposed to provide a number of [launch screens in varying resolutions](http://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-launchScreens), in 9-patch format for Android.  I don't see anywhere to customize how these 9-patch launch-screen .pngs are rendered.